# TeXstudio not large enough to use on a 4k display

Tags: texstudio, editors, screen

Using TeXstudio, the icons and menus are almost invisible on my 4k display (3840 x 2160 pixels, 28").

Is it possible to adjust the graphics so that TeXstudio could be usable on my 4k display?

Comment: Have you seen the posting [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5001)? You could try out the ones that work on your operating system. (Not all editors run on all operating systems...)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: The operating system you are using does the normal scaling. My personal experience is that Windows doesn't quite handle the scaling as good as some other OS's.

Comment: Hello everyone,
Thank you very much for your comments. Please don't close this topic yet. I checked out the posting `LaTex Editors/IDEs`, and I can see a vast number of IDEs over there. I get a bit dizzy when thinking about installing every single one of them, and evaluating the scaling issues on my display. I hope that in this community some people have years of experience with a multitude of IDEs, and some of them on 4k displays. So maybe one of them can recommend a good IDE for such displays.

Comment: Recommendations are off topic on any SE site, though.

Comment: It is more than just a recommendation that I need. The fact is that most IDEs on my system are practically unusable - because of the tiny buttons and invisible icons. I have a similar problem with the Eclipse IDE for programming.
Of course, a recommendation for a specific LaTex IDE with good scaling can help me. But maybe someone has a clever idea to make TeXstudio - or some other IDE - sizing correctly on a 4k. Maybe someone has a script that I can run to resize all the icons. Who knows?

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the icon size in TeXstudio preferences? With "show advanced options" you can find this under "gui scaling".

Comment: As far as I know, `WinEdt` asserts it is ‘dpi-aware’, so it should be adapted to 4K displays.

Comment: Thank you mr. @samcarter
Your solution really helped me. I'd like to vote your answer as the correct one, but you've put it in a comment. Please put it in an answer, and I'll vote for it ;-)

Comment: I really think this information would be better integrated into the answers in the main Q&A on IDEs/Editors. It will surely be much easier for other users to find that way. Especially if, as does seem plausible, more users have these displays as the technology becomes cheaper.

Comment: So there is a StackExchange website specifically for IDEs? That's awesome. I didn't know about that. What's the link?

Comment: @K.Mulier Glad I could help you to stay with TeXstudio, as this really is my favourite editor! I wish you much fun working on your tex projects with it!

Comment: @cfr I added this feature to the TeXstudio entry in the big IDE list. But I think this question should nevertheless be kept, as the big list serves an audience which is openminded looking for an editor, while this questions could help TeXstudio user with the too-small-icon-problem

Comment: @K.Mulier As you might have seen the question was closed as a duplicate. However if you would be willing to edit your question to be less broad and focus on "Texstudio symbols are to small in 4K", I think it would definitely be of value for further people with this problem and I will certainly vote to reopen it.

Comment: @samcarter If the question is edited to focus on TS, then, yes. If the question is 'which editors have feature X?' - as it was - it should be part of the main question, I think. But if the OP takes your suggestion, it is definitely valuable in its own right. (A link from the TS answer on the other question here for users of extreme displays might be in order, too.)

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include answers. This makes the site very confusing. Either ask the relevant person to answer or answer yourself, if that's appropriate.

Comment: @cfr Feel free to edit whatever you think improves the answer. I backed away from adding a link, as all other features would probably deserve one too.

Comment: I will edit my question. Give me 10 mins :-)

Comment: @samcarter Maybe just add suitability for extreme displays as a feature in the other answer?

Comment: @cfr I already added "adjustable icon size makes it suitable for high resolution displays" to the answer. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thankfully TeXstudio itself has a solution for this problem. In its preferences (with `show advanced options` active), there is a menu for `gui scaling` where you can easily adjust the size of the icons.

[image]

Comment: Thank you mr. Sam Carter. Your answer was really helpful!

Comment: @K.Muller a certain other member of this community corrected me once regarding my assuming another user's gender.  So, having made the mistake myself, I pass on the good advice.