# editor for ultra hd display

Tags: editors, ide

I have a laptop with 4K resolution.

Problem is that all programs that I find, are not adapted to this high resolution and all icons and text are way too small to use and read.

I was hoping there were some people who know a program to make latex documents like texmaker or texstudio for ultra hd displays so it is readable and useable.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is off-topic

Comment: why is this off-topic? I cant find an answer myself after already searching a long time. and this is a forum for questions about latex isnt it?

Comment: If all programs are not adapted to your high resolution I can't see any real connection to LaTeX

Comment: How about `vim`? `:)`

Comment: TeXStudio has adjustable icon size http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311997/texstudio-not-large-enough-to-use-on-a-4k-display/312018#312018

Comment: WinEdt has different sets of icons depending on the screen resolution (from 96 dpi to 192 dpi).

Comment: @samcarter I will look into it. Hopefully, this can fix it.

Comment: @samcarter many thanks. your solution helped me very much. Was exactly what I was looking for.