# Texmaker GUI is messy with high resolution screen

Tags: texmaker

I've just purchased a new brand laptop with 17 inch size of the screen. I've installed Texmaker and it is messy. The icons are very small and the GUI is not zoomed out automatically to fit the contents of the window. These are pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've already set the size of the icons to medium and the size of apps to 250 (i.e. the recommended size) for  the display.  I'm using Windows 10. Some fonts are blurry and a lot of people are complaining about this problem with no solution from Microsoft. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution for problems with Windos seems to be to simply stop using Microsoft and use a decent operating system.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Visual studio is looking decent to me. I don't know why  texmaker is looking terrible.

Comment: maybe try texstudio. It is very similar to texmaker, but lets you scale the icons http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311997/texstudio-not-large-enough-to-use-on-a-4k-display/312018#312018

Comment: Same mess with AlgoBox.

Comment: @Johannes_B, for the record, a similar problem is happening to me now that I've just installed Linux Mint 19 (till last week I was using Windows 10). It is not the same problem, in fact it is reversed: everything is HUGE on my HD display, so that barely half of the dialog windows is visible on the screen.

Comment: this is a cross platform QT issue nothing to do with platform it depends which apps are needing different settings so some users find scaling too big others too small this can be changed at each applications start up so one can upset the next etc. the switch for  version 5 is -dpiscale https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454353/texmaker-doesnt-work-properly-on-ubuntu-18-04/454393?r=SearchResults&s=2|15.1893#454393

Comment: For me this solution from pmassat worked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/486280/213

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the problem of icons in high-resolution screens has been submitted to the author of TeXmaker, and should be solved in next release.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Just expand the window (Drag and drop bottom right corner) for the "Configure Textmaker" GUI box. The small icons are annoying but you can work around this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain better how this could solve the given issue ...

Comment: in version 5 the start up can be changed see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467493/larger-font-in-texmaker/467971?r=SearchResults&s=1|33.1154#467971