# Texmaker GUI oversize icons

Tags: texmaker, resolution

I just installed Texmaker 5.0.2 for Ubuntu MATE 17.10 and the icons are unbearably large in the interface (see screenshots), even the configuration window takes up the whole screen.

I think my problem is the following - I have an ASUS ZenBook UX303LN, which comes with a QHD 3200x1800 screen, and guessing [by this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333103/texmaker-gui-is-messy-with-high-resolution-screen), Texmaker is trying to adjust for that. However, the screen has been replaced since a I bought it with a lower resolution 1920x1080 screen, and I'm guessing that's the reason the icons appear too large.

I've tried to remove all the toolbars I can, but still the buttons are huge and the spacing by the line numbers is too large. The configuration window doesn't seem to have options to change this. Any suggestions for a fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The sibling of `texmaker`, `texstudio` has adjustable icon size.

Comment: @samcarter thanks, will look into it, though I'm used to Texmaker and would like to keep using it.

Comment: Attaching another monitor (also 1920x1080) makes all the icons appear absurdly small, when the editor window is moved to that screen. I really liked that Texmaker split the source and PDF into two windows, but TeXstudio has as well. Am switching to TeXstudio now.

Comment: Welcome to texstudio :) I also switched from texmaker to it a few years ago and never regretted it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454353/texmaker-doesnt-work-properly-on-ubuntu-18-04/454393#454393

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Texmaker but with QT which at least in my machine (Linux Mate 18.04.2) is not properly set up.

I fixed it by setting `QT_SCALING_FACTOR=1`. Texmaker works beautifully with my UHD monitor now.

In my case, I do this in the command line, but you can set that variable somewhere else I guess:

```
$ QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1 texmaker
```