# Texmaker gui buttons and toolbar are small

Tags: texmaker

Related to this question (not a duplicate: my resolution is 1920x1080, the question and answer is outdated): [Texmaker GUI is messy with high resolution screen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333103/texmaker-gui-is-messy-with-high-resolution-screen)

The issue:
[image]

Windows 10, (resolution: 1920x1080), no custom font-size scaling is turned on, my laptop's resolution is set to the default 1920x1080.

This is the version I downloaded: https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you can't edit the icon size of the GUI buttons. From your picture, it looks for me like everything is normal sized. If you want to have an editor with customizable size, you probably should have a look at `texstudio`.

Comment: @Jan I can assure it is not "normal" sized, at least compared to the my other software programs and editors I have, e.g. intellij. This is oddly specific to Texmaker.